# Design optimization

Tags: database-design, table

I'm designing a database for a crm like software. Actually it's my first project so i'm learning on the run on this one.

I have customer and employee tables. I also have a history table for tracking the changes. But I want to ask, should I use separate history table for each master table? Right now I have customer, employee and contracts table. So, right now I have 3 separate history tables which have only ID difference, all other coloumns are same. If I will use one history table how should I determine for which master table the record was made?

Other question is about attachments table. I'll be saving files on server then copy the url to the attachments table. My question is same here, should I have three separate tables for employee, customer and contract attachments? If I will use one table how should I resolve the ID issue?

I have ID with prefix+auto increment in mind, but internet search says that it's a bad idea.

Thanks in advance..

Have a nice day..

PS: right now I'm just in a design stage. No SQL, just plain simple tables and relations.

Comment: What is the purpose of the history tables, are they part of a business scenario, or are they for tracking errors?

Comment: History tables are for auditing purposes. When and by whom data was added, deleted etc.

Comment: @theo in one system we used one history table with the structure like (autoinc, orig_table, primary_key_value, orig_field, datetime, old_value) to track changes - it is good enough for auditing, you just pick the right primary key value and table pair. But it is not very nice if you should show history for all fields by default. For attachments, you can have one table for them and 3 junction tables to associate it with 3 entities. Or if each entity can have at most 1 attachment, you add column with attachment_id to employee/customer/contract, but you usually want more of them.

Comment: @jkavalik what are the benefits and cons of creating one history table? and how should I connect this history table to all master tables? About the attachments, thank you for the solution. I had something similar to that in my mind.

Comment: @jkavalik if there will be 3 junction tables for attachment connection, wouldn't it will be better to use 3 separate image tables for each required master table? integrity vise I mean?

Comment: @theo benefit - only one table; con no possibility of "connecting it" but imho you should not connect it to anything, no FKs etc, if someone deletes a row, you still need to keep the history intact for proper audit but all FKs would be invalid.

Comment: @theo in 3 attachment tables you have to duplicate the stuff about file handling in your app (or parametrize it by destination table), so it is not so clean imho, but other than that I do not see much difference

Comment: @jkavalik, and what will be the benefit of using separate audit tables? and cons except using separate tables all over the place? How will it affect the speed of searching and data integrity?